# Groovy: Bad characters on 2.5.3 version but not in 1.5.7

Tags: groovy, encoding

I'm trying to display words with especial characters on groovy.
They are been replaced by "?" character on 2.5.3  version, but not using an older one like  1.5.7

Is a version bug?

Executing the same code with different groovy versions we get different results (the correct characters with the older and "?" with 2.5.3)

Running on RHL with JVM 1.8.0_161

```
def frase = "árbol è í ï Església Ramón"

println(frase);
byte[] testBytes = frase.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");

def frase1 = new String(testBytes, "ISO-8859-1")

println(frase1);
```

Expected output:

> árbol è í ï Església Ramón

Real output:

> ?rbol ? ? ? Esgl?sia Ram?n

Comment: Have you tried with `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8` depending on what you have there?

Comment: Yes: same result

Comment: it's possible that your console does not support those chars. do you have question marks for both `println`?

Comment: Hi daggett, yes: question marks for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a double problem there:

- The connection to the console via PUTTY needed to configure UTF8 for the console.
- Files must be in UTF8 format (there were in ISO)

Thanks a lot.